# Label for ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

The code snippet below shows what I'm trying to achieve. I'm basically assigning a label to the options in the select. The class on the label i.e `label-multi` applies some styling to the options as well. While this works fine for static options, when I try to use the `ng-repeat` loop, my options are displayed as `{{item.name}}` instead of the actual name of the item.

`{{item.name}}` is definitely available and works perfectly without the label. But applying this class `label-multi` seems to be interfering somehow. What could the problem here be?

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="label-multi" for="items">Items:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select multiple data-placeholder="Select Items..." id="items">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind to a `select` you need to use different syntax:

```
<select multiple id="items" ng-options="item.name for item in items" ng-model="selectedItem">

</select>
```

`ng-repeat` is only used to repeat data. `ng-options` is built for this specific data binding purpose

See docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: I did try this, even before your helpful post, but this time, nothing is rendered. Not even the `{{item.name}}`. I'm going to try and set up a Plunker for this.